# In order traversal of tree in scheme

Tags: tree, scheme, inorder

I would like to walk inorder through a Tree whose nodes contain an integer and return #t if all numbers are in order (i.e. the next number is greater or equal than the previous number).

My attempt so far

```
 (define (in-order tree number)  
    (cond [(leaf? tree) (>= leafnumber  number)]
          [(cons? leftsubtree) (in-order leftsubtree leftnumber)]
          [(cons? rightsubtree) (in-order rightsubtree rightnumber)]))
```

Somehow my number arguments seem to be wrong when I switch branches.
Do I need to use another variable to store these?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
; in-order : tree number -> number or #f
;   if all numbers in the tree are larger than number, then return the maximum number in tree,
;   otherwise 
(define (in-order tree number)
  (cond
    [(leaf? tree)   (if (>= leafnumber  number)
                        leafnumber               ; leafnumber is the largest number in tree
                        #f)]                     ; not all numbers in tree are smaller than number
    [else           (let ([leftnumber (in-order  leftsubtree number)])
                      (let ([rightnumber (in-order rightsubtree leftnumber)])
                        (and leftnumber
                             rightnumber)))]))

(in-order tree -inf.0)
```

Comment: How does the and work if leftnumber is a number and rightnumber is a boolean or the other way?